# Clear multiple files

Tags: bash

How can I clear/empty multiple files using bash?

For a single file you can use

```
> foo.log
```

But I've tried

```
> *.log;
find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log" | xargs >;
```

But they don't seem to work.  How can I do this?

Comment: My Linux box at work lets me say `truncate --size=0 *.log`.  Looks like that's part of the coreutils package, so it ought to be available on other flavors of Linux as well.

Comment: `> *.log` works in zsh, but unfortunately not in bash.

Answer (score 1):

The redirection must be performed in a shell, one at a time.

```
... -exec sh -c "> {}" \; ...
```

...

```
for f in *.log
do
  > "$f"
done
```

Comment: As using `{}` as a strict substring in an argument to `find` is not standardized, I suggest using `-exec sh -c '> "$1"' -- {} \;` instead.

Answer (score 0):

try this , it works :

```
 find . -maxdepth 1 -name "*.log" | xargs -t -n1 -I '{}' perl -e "open(I,'>{}')"
```